# mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/postgres/pgdata/data’: permission denied

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, timescaledb

I am trying to run a a project with docker-compose and I am getting `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/postgres/pgdata/data’: permission denied`. This problem only occurs on windows, on macOS the setup works fine. I think it has to do with user permissions on windows for docker.

The compose config:

```
volumes:
  volume_name:
    name: data

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg14.7-ts2.10.2-latest
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/home/postgres/pgdata
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
```

Any idea what I could do to fix this? Thanks in advance, help is much appreciated

Comment: First try creating a `data` directory in your `./data` directory, so Postgres doesn't need to do it.

Comment: @HansKilian Thanks! I updated my question with the volume creation. During the `docker up` process this directory gets created automatically with all files in it. Do you mean I should map the `data` directory to `/home/postgres/pgdata/data` instead of `/home/postgres/pgdata`?

Comment: Change `- ./data:/home/postgres/pgdata`to `- data:/home/postgres/pgdata`. Remove `./`.

Comment: @kometen Thank you! But changing the path results in `"data:/home/postgres/pgdata:rw" is used in service "postgres" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.`

Comment: Changing it from `./data` to `data` makes it a volume instead of a bind mount

Comment: @HansKilian @kometen Thank you! That worked. I needed to change the volume syntax too. To `volumes:  data:`. Using a volume instead of a bind mount did the trick. Very much appreciated . If someone wants to turn the comment into an answer I'd happily accept it

Comment: what is the difference between `home/postgres/pgdata/data` and `/var/lib/postgresql/data` directory? Seems there is nothing in `home/postgres/pgdata/data`

Answer (score 0):

You've insufficient rights to create the folder, which happens upon starting the container, as you provided:

```yaml
...
    volumes:
      - ./data:/home/postgres/pgdata
...
```

You can solve it by removing the bind volume, then just start the container.

This may be caused by the fact, you already have the **pgdata**, and the container tries to create it. In this case, bind the volume to the **pgdata** folder instead, which should be located inside your **data**. Or bind the volume to a different folder, and it is going to create the **pgdata** on it's own

[More on this subject](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/792)